# Set levels property for menu_subpages depdending on layout

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have the following typoscript configuration for the menu_subpages object:

```
tt_content.menu_subpages {
    dataProcessing {
        10 {
            levels = 1
            as = menu
            expandAll = 1
            includeSpacer = 1
        }
    }
}
```

To give the editor more flexibility I want to set the levels property depending on the selected layout of the content object. I've tried to use the CASE object but this doesn't seem to work:

```
tt_content.menu_subpages {
    dataProcessing {
        10 {
            levels = CASE
            levels {
                key.field = layout

                default = TEXT
                default.value = 1

                1000 = TEXT
                1000.value = 7
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `levels` is no object but a property you can't use it as an object.

Either you change it to an object:

```
tt_content.menu_subpages {
    dataProcessing {
        10 {
            levels.cObject = CASE
            levels.cObject {
               :
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Or you need to set the value inside a typoscript condition.

```
tt_content.menu_subpages {
    dataProcessing {
        10 {
            // default:
            levels = 1
            ...
        }
    }
}
[page['layout'] == 1000]
tt_content.menu_subpages.dataProcessing.10.levels = 7
[page['layout'] = 2000]
tt_content.menu_subpages.dataProcessing.10.levels = 3
[global]
```